# Spring Scheduled Cron jobs firing at wrong time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, spring-scheduled

I have a Spring Boot application with various schedulers that use the @Scheduled annotation. Some of the schedules are setup using fixedRate, others use cron. The fixedRate schedules run fine, but I've noticed that over the past month the actual time at which the cron schedules fire will vary by 1-2 hours each day.

i.e. a job with cron setup of

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 * * *")
```

will fire at 3:00 AM instead of 2:00 AM. It isn't happening every day either. It will run at the same time for a few days in a row, then something happens and it's off by another hour each time it is run until I restart the application.

The system time on the server is accurate, I'm all out of ideas here. Has anyone encountered this before?

**EDIT 1**

I put in some logging to determine if the jobs were mis-firing at the same interval, and the results seem random. Here are the start/end times for the aforementioned cron job over three days:

```
Format: Calendar.getInstance().getTime() (System.currentTimeMillis())

Start: Sat Oct 21 03:14:15 CDT 2017 (1508573655778)
End:   Sat Oct 21 03:22:24 CDT 2017 (1508574144708)

Start: Sun Oct 22 02:26:58 CDT 2017 (1508657218774)
End:   Sun Oct 22 02:35:12 CDT 2017 (1508657712492)

Start: Mon Oct 23 02:00:03 CDT 2017 (1508742003072)
End:   Mon Oct 23 02:08:11 CDT 2017 (1508742491493)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I did not have a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler setup, so I did not have a large enough thread pool set aside for running all of my scheduled jobs.

```
@Configuration
public class TaskSchedulerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(30);
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem (job scheduled at 1.30 AM, firing ± 9 AM, preceded by long running jobs, though there is some counter-evidence to single-threadedness) but this did not help me (Spring Boot 1.5, Spring 4.3). I tried as the return type both `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and `TaskScheduler`. I find the docs hard to understand on this :(

Comment: @Brian Smaith
is the above code sufficient . or do we ned to set it to the ScheduledTaskRegistrar.
do we need to use any other annotation to our scheduled method gets threads from the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.

Comment: @raj_kumar_junior This was running on an older application and version of Spring/Java. At the time of it's operation we did not have to configure a ScheduledTaskRegistrar. That might be the case on newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

Is it firing exactly 1 hour off each time, or is it variable as you mentioned?
How are you measuring the time at which it fires -- using logging? And how long does the method that you are annotating take to run? Log a message at the beginning and end of the method and compare those timestamps. You could try using

```
private static final String CRON_SCHEDULE = "0 0 2 * * ?";
private static final String USER_TIMEZONE = "America/New_York";
// ...
@Scheduled(cron = CRON_SCHEDULE, zone = USER_TIMEZONE)
/* your method here */
```

to see if the results are any different when you specify the timezone.

Comment: Hey Blake. I added some logging last Friday and let it run over the weekend to gather some results. I posted those results in my original question.

Comment: Yeah it seems like the start times are not firing on a schedule if that is what they are supposed to do. What other annotations do you have? is the scheduled method in a spring component, controller, or service class?

Comment: Finally figured it out. I did not have a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler setup, so there was not a big enough pool size to support all of my scheduled jobs. One would fire, the others would either get blocked, or put on some sort of internal queue, but when they eventually fired then the cron clock is offset by however long they were queued/blocked.